# Erlang - функция flatten. Время выполнения

Tags: erlang, time-complexity

Добрый день!

Есть функция которая выглядит вот так:

flatten ([]) -> [];

flatten([H|T]) -> H ++ flatten(T).

Входной лист в функцию может в себе содержать другие листы

К примеру:

flatten([[1,2,3],[4,7],[9,9,9,9,9,9]]).

Какое время выполнения этой функции (Time complexity)? И почему?

У меня получается O(n) где n это количество элементов во входном листе

К примеру:

flatten([[1,2,3],[4,7],[9,9,9,9,9,9]])    n=3

flatten([[1,2,3],[4,7],[9,9,9,9,9,9],[3,2,4],[1,4,6]])    n=5

Спасибо за помощь